Native React Stuck On "react-native run-android"
I‘m writing and making an Application using React Native. Planning to integrate it with a firebase database. Once I integrate my Metro and launched a code of
"npm run android"
It is just standing there doing nothing.
How do i fix this?
PS C:\Users\user\ecoBuddy> npm run android

ecoBuddy@0.0.1 android
react-native run-android

A code that I would be expecting it to come out is my application running on Android Emulator. Please anyone help me

Have you tried running npm run ios to start the iOS version so that you can diagnose to know if the problem is android specific or it's your project in general.
